# Looping through a list of strings, getting tuples instead

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, python-3.10

I have a problem and hope anyone here has seen something similar. What looks like a loop through a list of strings returns a tuple with data of unknown origin.

I am using Pycharm as my IDE. The error only happens if the code is executed in debug mode.

I have the following code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pool, Queue, Lock
import fnmatch

def find(_pat_set:set, _path:str, _ignore_pat: set = None,  _exclude_path_set: set = None):
    if _exclude_path_set is None:
        _exclude_path_set = set()
    if _ignore_pat is None:
        _ignore_pat = set()

    manager    = Manager()
    files_dict = manager.dict()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(_path):
        _ex_dir_set    = set()
        _full_dir_list = []
        for _dir in dirs:
            _full_dir = os.path.join(root, _dir)
            _full_dir_list.append(_full_dir)

        for _ex_dir in _exclude_path_set:
            _filtered = list(fnmatch.filter(_full_dir_list, _ex_dir))
            for f in _filtered:
                _ex_dir_set.add(os.path.basename(f))

        dirs[:] = sorted(list(set(dirs) - _ex_dir_set))

        _searched_files = []
        for _pat in _pat_set:
            _searched_files += list(fnmatch.filter(files, _pat))

        _ignore_files = []
        for _ig_pat in _ignore_pat:
            _ignore_files += list(fnmatch.filter(files, _ig_pat))

        _parse_files = set(_searched_files) - set(_ignore_files)

        files_dict[root] = dict((f, {}) for f in _parse_files)

    return files_dict

def main():

    exclude_set = {'*\\.*',
                   '*\\syn\\*',
                   '*\\tmp',
                   '*\\temp',
                   '*\\__pycache__'}

    _files = find(_pat_set={'*'}, _path='c:\\work\\git_project\\project', _ignore_pat={'*.rpt', '.*', '*.sdc'}, _exclude_path_set=exclude_set)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print('done')
```

It's a find routine to locate files and folders and build a shared dictionary which later is shared between threads to work on.

The problem is the following segment of the code:

```
    for _dir in dirs:
        _full_dir = os.path.join(root, _dir)
```

When I execute my code it gets the following error from the part of the code

```
  File "C:\Python310\lib\ntpath.py", line 143, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\genericpath.py", line 152, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'tuple'
```

And when I look in my debug window i have the following data

```
dirs = ['.git', '.settings', 'interface', 'scripts', 'tmp', 'tst_sw']
```

but the for value "_dir" contains this

```
_dir = ('c:\\work\\git_project\\project\\.git', ['hooks', 'info', 'lfs', 'logs', 'modules', 
       'objects', 'refs'], ['COMMIT_EDITMSG', 'config', 'description', 'FETCH_HEAD', 
       'gitk.cache', 'HEAD', 'index', 'ORIG_HEAD', 'packed-refs', 'sourcetreeconfig.json'])
```

Where does all that data come from? It should only have contained the string

```
_dir '.git'
```

There is no issue if the code is executed normally only in debug mode.

I hope someone has seen this before, I do not know if I can give any more information.

Regards

Comment: What is `Manager` and `fnmatch` in your code and what are the input values?

Comment: I've updated the text. But Manager is an multiprocess handler I use to share data between threads. fnmatch is able to process strings using wildcards etc.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why do you start (almost) all your variable names with `_`?

Comment: There's no need to convert the set to a list before calling `sorted()`.

Comment: Habit I think. I always start local values with underscore. I think it I do it because I do not hit any build in names.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, but not an answer or reason as to why it causes a problem.

I added a conditional breakpoint to the line:

```
_full_dir_list.append(_full_dir)
```

Which had a search condition in the string getting generated in the line above

```
_full_dir = os.path.join(root, _dir)
```

The breakpoint condition looked as follows.

```
'mod\\soc_2' in _full_dir
```

I do not know what or what but apparently it causes some interference in the list it was interesting though.

Removing the breakpoint removed the issue.

Comment: Breakpoints shouldn't affect the behavior of the code.

Comment: An exception might be if the condition has side effects. But `in` shouldn't have any side effects.

Comment: It looks like your value of `_dir` is the entire `(root, dirs, files)` tuple yielded by `os.walk()`. Maybe this is a bug in the debugger.

Comment: Yeah but apparently its trigger at least in some part by the break point because when I removed it the error was gone. and it was possible to set the break point elsewhere

Comment: Like I said, this seems like a bug in the debugger. Somehow the conditional breakpoint changed the variable value.

Comment: I agree.  I think id make a small repeatable example and then make a bug report to PyCharm